# Migrating content from legacy blogging platform to wordpress

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, blogs

I am working on a massive site for a client, but their current website (thousands of pages deep) is built on a legacy blogging platform that was built specifically for them in aspx. My job is to take all of the SQL tables filled with data(comments, categories, posts, titles, dates, etc) and convert them to a wordpress ready format. I want to be able to reformat the tables that I have into a format that wordpress can understand and process.

The tables are not even close to a match of the given wordpress format. I am looking at a major data migration and am looking for tools, resources, or people that may be of help. I am a web designer with little experience with mySQL or databases. Can anyone point me in a good direction here?

Comment: What is the "legacy blogging platform"?  Something you built in house or a third party software?

Comment: something that was built in house...there is no name for this blogging software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if there is some sort of tool that will help you migrate.  This will most likely boil down to good old fashioned SQL.

It sounds like you are trying to do a basic [Extract/Transform/Load operation (ETL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).  I'd start by reading up on that.  How many tables are you dealing with here?

I would also recommend printing out the Entity relationship model (database diagram) for both the new and old database structures and make sure you understand what data is going to go where.

Comment: thanks Abe- I am dealing with tens of thousands of tables, which is why I am looking for some sort of automation. I will read up on ETL

Comment: Your legacy DB has tens of thousands of tables?  I suspect that schema could be improved upon, but I guess that doesn't matter now...  Are any of the tables of a similar format?  If so i'm thinking you may be able to create a view that aggregates all that data which would simplify your ETL significantly.

Comment: Yes, the schema needs massive improvement! The tables are similar...it seems like this task is way outside my abilities, so I will be seeking professional help. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what wordpress reads, but looking to using the `mysqldump` function. this will save the SQL file and export it. Then just running simply change table commands, you can get it ready.